# How can I get rid of rust from painted metal mesh garden furniture

Tags: rust-removal

Does anyone have any ideas on how to remove the rust from this kettler garden furniture? I have used brillo pads and various methods which seems to remove the rust on the top surface but because it's mesh I can't seem to find a good way to get in between.

[image: rust on kettler mesh metal table]

Comment: 5 second internet search for rust remover, shows many products. Top for me would be naval jelly.

Comment: Or just use paint designed for this scenario. Related: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/8065/how-do-you-remove-paint-and-rust-from-outdoor-chairs?rq=1

Comment: Wasn't sure rust remover would get in the gaps, thanks. Will also look into the paint!

Comment: Yeah, except this is actually a pretty hard problem.  You'll find a year down the road that random hardware store cruft is well-marketed, but not really up to the task.

Comment: sandblasting is the most effective. you also might be able to power-wash enough of it off to get a good coat of paint on clean metal.